# Custom image for uibarbuttonitem iOs 6 landscape

Tags: iphone, background, uibarbuttonitem, ios6, landscape

I used this code to customize my barbutton for iOS 5 and it worked properly:

```
UIImage *barButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

When I rotate the device to landscape on iOS 5 the result is this:

[image]

Now with iOs 6 the result is this:

[image]

What happened and what I have to do to properly resize the image when the device is in landscape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide a landscape image and use that like so:

```
UIImage *barButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];
UIImage *barButton_land = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-button_land"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButton_land forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll draw the images and if it works I'll surely accept your answer!

Comment: @Lolloz89 Have you had a change to try my solution?

Comment: Sorry Mate, I forgot to check your answer, it worked very well! Thanks!